# Where did the "Noonien Wang"/"Kim Noonien Singh" story originally come from?

Tags: star-trek, gene-roddenberry

It's often said that Roddenberry chose the name "Khan Noonien Singh", and later "Noonien Soong", as an attempt at reuniting with a pilot he became friends with in WW2, with different stories saying it was someone named Kim Noonien Singh or Noonien Wang. But I've never seen a source for this, or even a quote from Roddenberry about it, just a bunch of places mentioning it as a factoid.

"Noonien" doesn't seem to be an actual name though, so far as I can tell? Every reference to it I can find is to Khan or Soong. Additionally, every source I've ever seen for it has been post-TNG, never anything more contemporary like an anecdote he shared on the 70s convention circuit, or behind-the-scenes books from the time like *Making of Star Trek*, or even fans just mentioning it in any of the "Trek" magazine compilations. Plus, the choice of character in Khan has always made the specific story just ring false to me. Or at least that it might just be a telephone game thing. The name *did* carry through all the later episode edits as Khan's name was settling down into its final form, and Roddenberry *did* push back against the studio to insist it be part of the character's name, so I can believe he got it from *somewhere*? But the details of the story just never really hung together to me.

Do we have any actual quotes from Roddenberry himself about this anecdote, or any sources from before TNG that confirm it was the source of Khan's name? What's the oldest source we have for it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Why do you disbelieve the standard story?

Comment: I *suspect* that Noonien is derived from [Nguyen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nguyen).

Comment: Link from a related post https://books.google.com/books?id=C-tNsbAhFiIC&lpg=PP1&dq=The%20Name%27s%20Familiar%3A%20Mr.%20Leotard%2C%20Barbie%2C%20and%20Chef%20Boy-Ar-Dee&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Singh&f=false

Comment: @DavidW It's been pointed out often that if that was the goal, using his name for one of Earth's worst tyrants is...odd, to say the least. But the fact that I've never once seen a _source_ for the story, just a repetition of it, is another big factor in why I've been suspicious, and why I'd like to find a source that's primary or secondary, or at least some sign of where it actually came from in the first place. If it was directly from Roddenberry, you'd expect to see an actual quote from him regarding it _somewhere,_ but I've never once seen a recounting include one.

Comment: @lucasbachmann I found that reference, yeah, but that's again just repeating the same story from everywhere else; it seems to be just a book of trivia related to well-known or iconic names. The warhistoryonline source that's linked off of Memory Alpha also seems to just be a repetition of the story with no reference to a real source.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's a possibility I've seen when it's been discussed elsewhere, yeah. I also found some theorizing on a Reddit thread that it might also be the Irish name "Noonan" and the pilot was Irish/Punjabi (since some versions of the story say it was an Indian pilot, not Chinese).

Comment: Justin you are correct it is very peculiar how unsourced it is. This is actually a huge gap and you have my deepest respect for calling it out. I'd speculate if Gene discussed the origin it would probably be circa 1988 to explain why Noonian showed up in both TOS and TNG.  Though perhaps STII publicity would have it.  Of course the 1970s was hungry for any trivia even about a minor villain of the week- so some fanzine transcript of a convention could be the answer.  (I don't think it's a fake story just one from an era of poor record keeping and 50 year old paperbacks)